# How to start remote windows-services using Ansible

Tags: ansible, windows-services, remote-server

I have 3 servers and all of my Ansible scripts are running on Server 1, hence my Playbook only mentions Server 1 in hostname. I now need to start a Windows service on Server 2. I am not sure how to do that.

I have already tried using win_service with delegate_to option.
I also tried to run
win_shell "Get-Service - Name ServiceName - computername Server 2",
but that did not work (I have checked the host file and connection between server 1 and 2). I tried to run a ps1 file (exists on Server 1) with the above Powershell command, but that did not help either.

All the above attempts return back the error that the service does not exist on Server 1 hence cannot start it.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at playbooks with [multiple plays](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html). They allow you to specify different hosts for each set of tasks.

For example:

```
---
- hosts: group1

  tasks:
  - task1: ...

- hosts: group2

  tasks:
  - task2: ...
```

Comment: Thanks, but due to other constrains, that is not an option.